# Add custom validator on phonenumber in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2.3

On checkout I want users to be able to use 0-9 + and - in the phone field. I'm trying to add a custom validator in my module but I can't seem to get it to work. I followed the steps in [this tutorial](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_order.html]) but in the text is says it's only for the second checkout step but I need it for the first.

How would I get this to work for the phone field? Thanks in advance.

I currently have this:

*checkout_index_index*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">

                                                    <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">

                                                            <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="validate-phonenumber"
                                                                          xsi:type="string">true
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="stripped-min-length"
                                                                          xsi:type="string">10
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>

                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">

                                                    <item name="additional-payment-validators" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="validate-phonenumber" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">
                                                                    BB_Checkout/js/view/validate-phonenumber
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

*model/validate-phonenumber.js*

```
define(
[],
function () {
    'use strict';
    return {
        /**
         * Validate something
         *
         * @returns {boolean}
         */
        validate: function() {
            return utils.isEmptyNoTrim(value) || !/[^\d\+\-]/.test(value);
        }
    }
}
 );
```

*view/validate-phonenumber.js*

```
define(
[
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators',
    'BB_Checkout/js/model/validate-phonenumber'
],
function (Component, additionalValidators, validatePhonenumber) {
    'use strict';
    additionalValidators.registerValidator(validatePhonenumber);
    return Component.extend({});
}
 );
```

Comment: I ended up overwriting rules.js like the answer in [this](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Add-custom-validator-on-phonenumber-in-checkout/m-p/94037#M4425) topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up overwriting rules.js.

I added the following:

```
'validate-phonenumber': [
        function(value) {
            if (value.length < 10) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return utils.isEmptyNoTrim(value) || !/[^\d\+\-\(\) ]/.test(value);
            }
        },
        $.mage.__('Voer een geldig telefoonnummer in bijvoorbeeld: 0612345678.')
    ],
```

checkout_index_index.xml

```
<item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="validate-phonenumber"
                     xsi:type="boolean">true
         </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

And in requirejs-config.js I added this:

```
   'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/rules': 'BB_Checkout/js/lib/validation/rules-overwrite',
```

Comment: thanks for sharing. works great.. :)

Comment: i wish you could write this answer in detail to simply understand

Answer (score 0):

I know that is old post but I had this problem now.

The other solution is prepare custom UI Component and override the validate method. Then You avoid to override whole rules file.

*app/code/NAMESPACE/Checkout/view/base/web/js/form/element/text-phone.js*

```
define([
  'mageUtils',
  'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
  'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator'
], function (utils, Abstract, validator) {
  'use strict'

  return Abstract.extend({
    defaults: {
      visible: true,
      label: '',
      error: '',
      uid: utils.uniqueid(),
      disabled: false,
      links: {
        value: '${ $.provider }:${ $.dataScope }'
      }
    },

/**
 * Has service
 *
 * @returns {Boolean} false.
 */
hasService: function () {
  return false;
},

/**
 * Has addons
 *
 * @returns {Boolean} false.
 */
hasAddons: function () {
  return false;
},

/**
 * Calls 'initObservable' of parent
 *
 * @returns {Object} Chainable.
 */
initObservable: function () {
  this._super()
    .observe('disabled visible value');

  return this;
},

/**
 * Validates itself by it's validation rules using validator object.
 * If validation of a rule did not pass, writes it's message to
 * 'error' observable property.
 *
 * @returns {Object} Validate information.
 */
validate: function () {
  var value = this.value(),
    result = validator(this.validation, value, this.validationParams),
    message = !this.disabled() && this.visible() ? result.message : '',
    isValid = this.disabled() || !this.visible() || result.passed;

  if(isValid){
    var regex = /^[0-9./\-()+ ]+$/;
    isValid = !value || regex.test(value);
    if(!isValid){
      message = 'YOUR MESSAGE';
    }
  }

  this.error(message);
  this.error.valueHasMutated();
  this.bubble('error', message);

  if (this.source && !isValid) {
    this.source.set('params.invalid', true);
  }

  return {
    valid: isValid,
    target: this
  };
}

  })
})
```

You can override it using plugin and afterMerge method

*app/code/NAMESPACE/Checkout/Plugin/AttributeMerger.php*

```
 public function afterMerge(parentAttributeMerger $subject, array $result): array
    {

    if (array_key_exists('telephone', $result)) {
        $result['telephone']['component'] = 'NAMESPACE_Checkout/js/form/element/text-phone';
    }

    return $result;
}
```

*app/code/NAMESPACE/Checkout/etc/frontend/di.xml*

```
<type name="\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger">
        <plugin name="namespace_attribute_merger" type="\NAMESPACE\Checkout\Plugin\AttributeMerger"/>
    </type>
```

Comment: Hi, I had tried your solution but validation is not done by the plugin. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: @AskBytes has you added also custom component? Clear the whole caching, rebuild the statics?