# How to add custom validation to checkout phone field

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, validation

I have checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="payments-list" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="magedelight_cybersource-form" xsi:type="array" >
                                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="form-fields" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <!--<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">-->
                                                                                    <!--<item name="customPhoneValidation" xsi:type="string">true</item>-->
                                                                                <!--</item>-->
                                                                            </item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

How to add custom validation to checkout phone fild?
I added the HTML file in this way
requirejs-config.js

```
map: {
    "*": {
        customPhoneValidation: "Tupperware_Party/js/model/customPhoneValidation"
    }
}
```

customPhoneValidation.js

```
requirejs([
'jquery',
'jquery/ui',
'jquery/validate',
'mage/translate'], function($){
'use strict';
$.validator.addMethod(
    "customPhoneValidation",
    function(value, element) {
        /*logic*/
        return false;
    },
    $.mage.__("Your validation message")
);
```

});

in form

```
<form data-mage-init='{"customPhoneValidation":{}}'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @Aleksandr Boika try below way.

> checkout_index_index.xml

```
<item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
  <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="validate-phonenumber"
                 xsi:type="boolean">true
     </item>
</item>
```

> requirejs-config.js

```
'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/rules': 'Modulename_Checkout/js/lib/validation/rules-overwrite',
```

> rules-overwrite.js

```
'validate-phonenumber': [
    function(value) {
        if (value.length < 10) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return utils.isEmptyNoTrim(value) || !/[^\d\+\-\(\) ]/.test(value);
        }
    },
    $.mage.__('Voer een geldig telefoonnummer in bijvoorbeeld: 0612345678.')
],
```

For more reference [Click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225164/add-custom-validator-on-phonenumber-in-checkout)

I hope it helps!

Comment: it would be highly appreciate if you can write a complete answer, So everyone can understand easily.