# Magento2: How to validate Phone number field for specific expression in Customer Registration Form?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I want to validate the Phone number field for the specific Reg exp, the Number type is (999) 999-9999 how to validate in customer registration form in magento2

Comment: Check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225164/add-custom-validator-on-phonenumber-in-checkout

Comment: I want in customer registration form @Sumit

Comment: If possible please write answer here step by step @Sumit